# c# byte array xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, arrays

I got a byte array

```
public byte[] values;
```

I fill it with data

```
new byte[64];
```

I serialize it and I get the following XML part:

```
<values>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
</values>
```

I found the following solution here in SO:

```
[XmlElement("values", DataType = "hexBinary")]
        public byte[] values;
```

Now I get the same XML as above just with "0" instead of "A".

When I serialize e.g. a Int16/Int32/sbyte array. I get something like this in XML:

```
<values>0</values>
<values>0</values>
<values>0</values>
```

In a **vertical** arrangement.

Now my question: *Is it possible to get a byte array also in a vertical arrangement?* Like:

```
    <values>00</values>
    <values>00</values>
    <values>00</values>
```

Mark

Comment: Have you tried serializing a List<byte>

Comment: I get an Error when I try to serialize a List. I don't think that is possible. "There was an error reflecting type'...' "   SORRY: I missed to delete the DataType Xml Tag. It works!

Comment: List<byte> is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks the_ajp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
    public List<byte> Bytes { get; set; }
}

var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
xml.Serialize(File.Open("test.xml",FileMode.OpenOrCreate),
              new Test
              {
                  Bytes = new List<byte> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
              });
```

results in a xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Bytes>
    <unsignedByte>0</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>1</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>2</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>3</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>4</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>5</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>6</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>7</unsignedByte>
  </Bytes> 
</Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd have to explicitly go create a new XML element for each byte in the array.  You might as well use a `List<byte>` or `Array<byte>` for doing that, instead of a raw array.

As the_ajp said in the comment.

If you're getting an error trying to serialize the list, you've done something wrong.  Post the code, perhaps we can help.

Comment: I mentioned that you said it :)

Comment: Ye thanks, I already commented above, I've missed to delete the DataType = heyBinary part.